# How to enable commenting system in Wordpress

Tags: comment-form, comments-template

I am learning how to create custom Wordpress theme from [this page](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/08/how-to-code-a-wordpress-3-0-theme-from-scratch)
and everything is working except commenting system because they haven't described how to enable it (they only used `<?php comment_form(); ?>` to insert form into template). I can see my comment in the backend but not in the page itself (I can see a link showing **1 comment** but when I click it nothing happens). Obviously I need some PHP code to show my comments but have no idea where to start! I am stuck because I just started to learn Theme Development and my PHP knowledge is limited. 
Can anyone give me a suggestion or a solution for that problem? It would a mean a lot to me. 
Index php looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="blog">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <div class="entry"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation">
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

My Wordpress page [HERE](http://robertpeic.com/wordpress_template/)
Thank You!!

Comment: There's a syntax error when trying to view comments: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/robertpe/public_html/wordpress_template/wp-content/themes/New 3.0 Theme/single.php on line 28`

Comment: I Know trying to make it work. Try look now.

Comment: Add in `comments_template();` before your `endwhile;`.

Comment: Now I have two comments fields but my comments still doesn't show...

Comment: @stealthyninja as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `comments.php` template and add in

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
</ol>
```

This should display comments, pingbacks and trackbacks. See the Codex for [**`wp_list_comments()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) for help on how to style and separate or to display just comments.

Comment: I will say just this: stealthyninja THANK YOU for your effort and your time it worked like a charm you have just made my day beautiful!!!